# How to rename .pdf file in Android

Tags: java, android, file, file-rename

I want to rename the PDFs in my PDF viewer app but my code is not working

```
renamed = "New Name"

File file = pdfFiles.get(position);
if (!renamed.equals("") || !renamed.equals(file.getName())) {
   boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(renamed + ".pdf"));
   if (success) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Renamed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
      Toast.makeText(context,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

}

it is always Toasting me Error

Comment: `File file = pdfFiles.get(position);` That does say nothing about full path of the file. Should we guess where that file resides?

Comment: can you show me how to do that? please I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: rename value is edittext.getText().toString()

Comment: `new File(renamed + ".pdf")` You should use a full path for the File class. Not only a file name.

Comment: Showing how to do that,? You should tell us the value of file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Please can you show me how? I don't know about it

Comment: `file.renameTo(new File(file.getAbsolutePath(), renamed + ".pdf"))` like this

Comment: ???? Print it. Log it. Or toast it.

Comment: It looks as if you do not know what it means the value of a variable. The value of a String for example  if you have `String renamed = "New Name"` Then the value of variable renamed is "New Name". And we know how you wanna rename the file. Now tell the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` so we know which path you use.